# Any way to disable or clear chrome devtools call stack panel

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a code for ascii file process.

The file has thousands of points.

My code has 6 or 7 funcions I call for every point.

While debugg, I view how chrome goes slower and slower 
I suspect that the problem is that the call stack panel is filled wit thousands of calls.

The problem would be fixed if I could temporary disable the call stack panel or clear it from code ...
Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: My guess it's the debugger itself having trouble coping with the large amount of call stack data. I tried removing the call stack panel and that didn't noticeably improve performance. For anyone else, here's a jsFiddle replicating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/4yLuqcfm/

Comment: Yeah, there's a 18s lag between telling the debugger to resume and when it says it's resumed (http://i.imgur.com/GpinfpA.png). Might be easiest to rewrite your code to not go so deep in the call stack.